# Не получается оформить показ погоды в PyOwm

Tags: python, pyowm

Я узнав как сделать русский язык для PyOwm, столкнулся с ещё одной проблемой. Я хотел сделать показ погоды не как "detailed_status = ясно" а например: "В Москве сейчас пасмурно".
Вот код:

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils import config as cfg
config = cfg.get_default_config()
config['language'] = 'ru'

owm = OWM('[token]', config)

place = input("Укажите город/страну: ")

mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather

print("В городе " + place + " сейчас " + w.get_detailed_status())
```

На выходе получаю:

```
print("В городе " + place + " сейчас " + w.get_detailed_status())
AttributeError: 'Weather' object has no attribute 'get_detailed_status'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите `get` и круглые скобки.

***Пример:***

```py
print("В городе " + place + " сейчас " + w.detailed_status)
```